# How can I find the biggest magnitude present in a numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, element, magnitude

Say I have:

```
A = np.array( [1,2,3,-8] )
```

I need a function that would return 8

I know it's a simple one, but instant Google-Fu failed, hence some merit in populating SO maybe.

Comment: That's it! Could you put it as an answer?

Comment: Gimme a moment :) (SO does not allow you to accept an answer until several minutes after you've asked the question)

Comment: Sorry to rush you, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try running :

```
 np.abs(A).max()
```

Comment: Also see `argmax` if you need its index.